# NSColorWell to control action 

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to set up a conditional method based on the state of a colorWell object.

According to the Support docs "isActive" returns a Boolean. How would I do this?

Thanks.

Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seriously asking how to branch based on a boolean property? The [if statement](http://c.comsci.us/syntax/statement/if.html) will help you…

```
if( [colorWell isActive] )
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```